# How to get image from url from the database?

Tags: php, database, get-posts

Hello everyone I need to fetch rows and display them. This is not a aproblem, but! I have column icon, which contains the url of the icon, so I should display the image from the url. Could you tell me how to display that image?

```
  <?php

    global $wpdb;
    // this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of 
    wordpress
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "tablename";
    // this will get the data from your table
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>


      <div class="innerApp">
        //THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC LINE
        <img  class="appLogo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?><?php 
       echo $retrieved_data->icon?>">   
        <p class="justTextTextApp"><?php echo $retrieved_data->NAME?></p>
        <p class="justDescription"><?php echo $retrieved_data->description?>
        </p>
      </div>

        <?php 
                                                   }
        ?>
       </ul>
```

Comment: what is url of your image? how does it related to page? does it static or dinamic?

Comment: The url is just the place from where the image is derieved. It has no relation with the page. So basically, we have url(the icon url) and I assume I should use it as src"" in my <img>. But the table is custom, so I am not sure which function I can use.

Comment: does `$retrieve_data` contain your image url?

Comment: my url is in $retrieved_data->icon

Comment: then why do you use `bloginfo('template_url')`?

Comment: Can you show what are you getting in `print_r( $retrieve_data);` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend to escape all values before output, e.g. `echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->NAME )`.

The same for the image:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $retrieved_data->icon ); ?>" />
```

You can read more about [Securing Output](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/) in the developer handbook.